# Joining a table on a column that needs to be casted in order to be joined on

Tags: sql, data-science, data-analysis, presto

I am trying to join on a column that needs to be converted or cast as varchar to match that same column in a different table. But the way I am trying here I get an error of **'<>' cannot be applied to boolean, varchar(4)**, (second to last line) where I join table c on customer id = the casted cust id in table c, is there a way I can do this?

```
    SELECT e.city,
       e.time
       m.id,
       cast(c.cust_id AS varchar) as customer_id2
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY eid,
                                    e.phase
                       ORDER BY e.time ASC) rnk
   FROM tablea e
   WHERE e.day BETWEEN date '2019-05-08' AND date '2019-05-08') e
JOIN tableb m ON e.id = m.id
JOIN tablec c ON m.customer_id = cast(c.cust_id AS varchar)
WHERE rnk = 1 and c.indicator <> 'true'
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful for others trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry adding correction now @GordonLinoff

Comment: Maybe you should type `true` instead of `'true'` right at the end.

Comment: ` '<>' cannot be applied to boolean, varchar(4)` error suggests there might be a problem with `c.indicator <> 'true'` comparison. Did you try with `true` instead of `'true'`?

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks!